# How to add List<Students> as a field in Entity Courses

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I want to create courses where multiple students can enroll. I made StudentsEntity class, and CourseEntity class and added the required fields inside them, one of the fields in the course entity is List of Students so that I could call an endpoint and I could get the list of all students associated with that particular course.

But looks like I am not able to add the list of students directly as a field as H2 db column. Help me resolve this.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="Courses")
@Data
public class CourseEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="course_Name")
    private String courseName;
    
    @Column(name="students")
    **private List<StudentEntity> students;**
}
```

above is the list I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

Use association mappings to model the relationship between two database tables as attributes in your entity.

JPA and Hibernate support the same associations as you know from your relational database model, all are described in [the blog post](https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/). It's important to understand them correctly.

For this particular case, you can focus on the `@ManyToMany` association, since many students can be enrolled in many courses.